# Adding a secondary node on another computer?

Tags: elasticsearch

The running instance of elasticsearch on a server is running with all defaults, no changes.

How can I scale horizontally to another server on another network?

Where do you specify this?

I only see one `elasticsearch.yml` file in the config directory, do I have to make a new config file for each cluster/node etc I would like to enable?  The config file appears to be for one instance only.  How do I tell it to use it as a master and the secondary server outside of the network as a secondary instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the other node, you install ES as usual and, depending on the network characteristics and your preference, you change or not things in `elasticsearch.yml` of both ES instances.

ES uses by default multicasting on the network to discover nodes in the same cluster. A cluster is defined by "cluster.name" property you can find in `elasticsearch.yml` file. Nodes with the same "cluster.name" will join the same cluster. If using multicasting, you need to make sure, first the multicasting is available in your network configuration, and then that you don't have firewalls or any other things that could block communication between the nodes (like port 54328).

You can also use unicasting for nodes discovery, where the address of each node is specified in `elasticsearch.yml`. For more details about this, check `elasticsearch.yml` file as it has some good description of these settings. For example, disable multicasting:

`discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false`

and configure unicasting:

`discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2:port"]`

Comment: Ok I think I understand this correctly to use the last line of your answer as the way to define the secondary node host?  All other settings should be for the local instance?  The .yml file only looks like its for one es server, not for more. So I'm guessing every node I want on the same machine will have to be in a additional instance/installation of es?

Comment: No, you can also use multicasting for nodes that are not on the same machine/node. By default, ES uses 224.2.2.4 group for multicasting. Installing ES on another node and as part of the same cluster means having another ES installation. With multicasting the .yml file can stay the same for both ES instances. With unicasting, one node needs to have the address and port of the other member of the cluster. Unicasting and multicasting are two different options for ES clustering. You can use one or the other.